# low performance in Sql connection

Tags: performance-testing

Hi everybody could you please answer my question?
have you ever faced with the below situation?
consider that you made a UDL connection file to test connection from client to the SQL server
1)you connect with listener name(dns name I meant) by AD user
2)you connect with listener name(dns name I meant) by SQL user
3)you connect with Listener IP by AD user
4)you connect with Listener IP by SQL user

You have very low performance close to time out in the third one(3), unfortunately this one is used by some applications in my environment. could you interpret the behaviors of that?

Answer (score 0):

If SQL server account login is fast, but AD account login is slow, I would start by just running a test to see how fast the logins are verifying.

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
Console.WriteLine("Testing login type...");

// create a "principal context" - e.g. your domain (could be machine, too)
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN"))
{
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword");
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"The test took {stopwatch.Elapsed} to finish");
}
```

Comment: I checked this code and the result is: "The test took 00:00:00.3994623 to finish " could it be possible to help me with the rest of solution that I should do  ?

Answer (score 0):

I can understand the solution accidentally.
I couldn't interpret the reason because I'm not a network administrator.

actually when you add listener to high availability you need two parts:

`ping [your listener name]` ==> it returns ip of you listener

and

`ping -a [ your listener IP]` ==> this should return [your listener name]

and this is my missing part. I meant it doesn't return my listener name. If network administrator describe it well the low performance would go away.